# ajax call with jQuery Mobile to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a problem in my code, I call the php by an ajax call, I have the right answere (I tested the json answere by some alerts), my problem is when I append the data to my list-view, I have no data in my list even using the "refresh". Can you help me to find the bug please.

He gives me this error:
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Here the code in HTML and jQuery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({url: "SubCategory.php",
                dataType: "json",
                jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    ajax.parseJSONP(result);
                },
                error: function (request,error) {
                    alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                }
            });
        var ajax = {
                    parseJSONP:function(result){
                        $.each(result, function(i, row) {
                            $('#select-subCategory').append('<option value="'+row.id+'">Annuncio: '+row.name+'</option>');
                        });
                        $('#select-subCategory').listview('refresh');
                    }
                }
});
</script>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="SubCategory.php">
        <select id="select-subCategory" data-native-menu="false">
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

And this is my php file

```
class SCategory
{
    public $id;
    public $name;
}
$SubCategories = array();
$SubCategories[0] = new SCategory;
$SubCategories[0]->id = 0;
$SubCategories[0]->name = 'first';
$SubCategories[1] = new SCategory;
$SubCategories[1]->id = 1;
$SubCategories[1]->name = 'second';
$SubCategories[2] = new SCategory;
$SubCategories[2]->id = 2;
$SubCategories[2]->name = 'third';
$SubCategories[3] = new SCategory;
$SubCategories[3]->id = 3;
$SubCategories[3]->name = 'fourth';
echo json_encode($SubCategories);
```

**SOLUTION**

> Delete 'data-native-menu="false"' from HTML, (maybe is true by
>   default), so the select in HTML become simply

```
<select id="select-subCategory" ></select>
```

> then the listview will refresh and
>   appear!! :)

Comment: `select` isn't a `listview`, you should use `.selectmenu("refresh")`.

Comment: I fixed it this weekend, and maybe you are right @Omar, the solution I foud it was delete 'data-native-menu="false"' from HTML, so the select become <select id="select-subCategory" ></select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem :

Delete 'data-native-menu="false"' from HTML, (maybe is true by default), so the select in HTML become simply

```
<select id="select-subCategory" ></select>
```

then the listview will refresh and appear!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$('#select-subCategory').append(`

and id is `selectsubCategory`

but should be used

```
$('#selectsubCategory').append(
```

Comment: Sorry, it just my error while coping it here, even setting the same name it doesn't works

Comment: I fixed it, look at the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine

```
$.each(result, function(key, row) {
    $.each(row, function(id, name) {
        $("<option>").val(id).text(name).appendTo($('#selectsubCategory'));
    });
});

$('#select-subCategory').listview();
```

if you are loading the entire list you will need to initialize it not to refresh it

Comment: No, it doesn't works, he gives me this error
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: this error is on this line `$('#select-subCategory').listview('refresh');` what if you skip it?

Comment: if I skip it I have no result, no error but no result in my view, the refresh is needed to refresh my list...

Comment: if you are loading the entire list you will need to initialize it not refresh it. So try just `$('#select-subCategory').listview();`

Comment: I fixed it, look at the solution :)